# Android menu chosing by pressing

Tags: android, select, menu, swipe

I'm looking to do something on Android.

I want to press with my finger some image for like a second and make it appear a menu; however, I would still have to be pressing the screen while I move to the chosen option. From the moment I quit my finger from that option it would be the selected.

I've been looking for tutorial's and "how to"s but I can't have a clue on how to do that. I would appreciate some help in this topic

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Its better to display the **Context_Menu** `onLongClickListener` and let the user to chose the option.

The idea of keeping the screen pressed its not really a good idea.
Most of the people are unaware of that. Whereas, if u just simply display a context menu and let user click the desired option, it will be better.